# Laravel 5 rebuild model from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have the following code placing an `organisation` object into session:

```
session()->put('tenant.organisationActive', $organisation->toArray());
```

I have a form (using `laravelcollective`) that allows the user to edit the content of `organisation`

```
{!! Form::model($organisation, ['route' => 'setup.organisation', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
    @include('setup.organisation-form')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I want to load the `$organisation` from `session`, I have tried this:

```
$organisation = new Organisation;
if (session()->has('tenant.organisationActive.id')) {
    $organisation = collect(session('tenant.organisationActive'));
}
return view('setup.wizard', compact('organisation');
```

I can see via `dd` the `organisation` data is passed as a collection in the above example, but it is a collection of one array containing the data. The page fails to open with:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Collection::$address1
```

If I do not use the `collect` function, the error becomes

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I suspect that the reason for this is that `laravelcollective` is accessing a property in a model, rather than an array key.

If so how to rebuild the object based on the session array? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doh! Long day. The answer is:

```
$organisation = new Organisation(session('tenant.organisationActive'));
```